# Message too long for UDP socket after setting sendBufferSize()

Tags: java

I'm trying to send a UDP datagram (containing a protocol buffers message) and getting message too long exceptions:

```
java.io.IOException: Message too long
at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:625)
```

I've set the send buffer size, and checked the return value from getBufferSize(), and it's larger than the message:

```
byte[] b = msg.toByteArray();
            System.out.println( "Serialised message in " + b.length + " bytes (max length: " + network.getSendBufferSize() + ")");
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket( b, b.length, host, port );
            network.send( p );
```

Outputs:

```
VM version: 16.3-b01-279
Runtime version: 1.6.0_20-b02-279-9M3165
Vendor: Apple Inc.    
Serialised message in 69424 bytes (max length: 531075)
Problem sending packet: java.io.IOException: Message too long
```

I could understand if it was refusing to set a large sized buffer, but it seems to be setting whatever I ask, and then not honoring it.

This is on OSX; I've tried both with 1.6 and 1.5

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. I was hoping to avoid the hassle of a TCP setup, but clearly that's not possible. It's a shame that Java doesn't correctly report the possible buffer size though (and there's nothing in the API docs either).

Comment: There is no evidence here that Java doesn't 'report the possible buffer size correctly'. There is no API that actually does that in the first place. There is only the actual send buffer size: the *underlying operating system* is free to modify the buffer size  you ask for, up or down; and that's not the only limit on UDP payload size.

Comment: @EJP: the docs for getSendBufferSize say "Get value of the SO_SNDBUF option for this DatagramSocket, that is the buffer size used by the platform for output on this DatagramSocket."  It doesn't seem unreasonable to interpret this as the actual size which can be used. I find "platform" there quite ambiguous, and read it as reporting what the underlying operating system was going to do. I was assuming that setSendBufferSize wouldn't always give you the size you asked for, but getSendBufferSize would tell you what you could actually have. Thanks for the clarification, though!

Comment: That conclusion is only reasonable if you think that the current platform knows the path MTU to the destination before you have used it, which doesn't even make sense. getSendBufferSize() does indeed tell you what you have, but what you have is a kernel buffer, not a model of the path MTU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UDP datagrams can't be larger than 64K

Comment: Or even that big.

Answer (score 10):

1. The limit on a UDP datagram payload in IPv4 is 65535-28=65507 bytes, and the practical limit is the MTU of the path which is more like 1460 bytes if you're lucky.
2. When UDP is fragmented, it *loses* the datagram if a fragment is lost, because there is *no* retransmission.

Use TCP.

Comment: how can sure we make we send >65535 bytes of data everytime?

Comment: @guru_001 You *cannot* send more than *65507* bytes at *any* time, *as I have already stated.* Some times I wonder why I bother.

Answer (score 1):

UDP has a maximum limit a little bit short of 64K. Your message is over that limit.

Besides, you shouldn't use UDP at all for such large message. When UDP is fragmented, it has to retransmit the whole thing if one segment is lost. Use TCP.

Comment: UDP doesn't retransmit anything.