# Truncate DatagramPacket byte array

Tags: java, sockets

I'm working with `DatagramPacket`s and `DatagramSocket`s to make a client/server situation. I have a working project with a simple client and server. The client will send a serialized object to the server and that's it.

The code shown below works perfectly. I'll post the entire classes so in case anybody wants to run the code it should be possible.

What I'm trying to do is truncate the sent data into an array that just fits (based on [How to get rid of the empty remaining of the buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229064/how-to-get-rid-of-the-empty-remaining-of-the-buffer)).

When I print out the length I sent and the length I received I do get this output:

```
GameClient: sent 330 bytes to the server
GameServer: received 330 bytes
```

What I did first on the receiving side was this:

```
        socket.receive(packet);
        // Deserialize the object.
        TestObject received = TestObject.deserialize(packet.getData());
```

But, I have set the buffer size to an arbitrary size, so I figure I should put the actual bytes in a byte array that fits the object. So I tried the following:

```
        socket.receive(packet);
        // Truncate the data into a smaller byte array.
        int actualSize = packet.getLength();
        byte[] actualPacket = new byte[actualSize];
        System.arraycopy(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), data, 0, packet.getLength());

        // Deserialize the object.
        TestObject received = TestObject.deserialize(actualPacket); // Does not work.
```

However, this code gives me the expection

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000
```

which is thrown in the `deserialize` method of `TestObject` at the first line:

```
        ObjectInputStream iStream = new ObjectInputStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
```

What could be the problem here? The data is an exact copy, right?

**OBJECT TO SEND**

```
package net;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class TestObject implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int value;
    public double anotherValue;
    public byte[] fillMe;

    public TestObject(int value)
    {
        super();
        this.value = value;
        fillMe = new byte[123];
    }

    public TestObject(int value, double anotherValue)
    {
        super();
        this.value = value;
        this.anotherValue = anotherValue;
    }

    public static byte[] serialize(TestObject o)
    {
        try
        {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(2048);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(o);
            oos.close();
            // get the byte array of the object
            byte[] obj = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
            return obj;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static TestObject deserialize(byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            ObjectInputStream iStream = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
            TestObject obj = (TestObject) iStream.readObject();
            iStream.close();
            return obj;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**SERVER (receiving end)**

```
package net;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.SocketException;

import utils.Printer;
import engine.board.GameBoard;

public class GameServer extends Thread
{   private static int BUFFER_SIZE = 64000; //64k buffer
    private static final int SERVER_LISTENING_PORT = 1234;
    private DatagramSocket socket;
    private GameBoard game;

    public GameServer(GameBoard game)
    {
        this.game = game;
        try
        {
            this.socket = new DatagramSocket(SERVER_LISTENING_PORT);
        } catch (SocketException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data,  data.length);
            try
            {
                socket.receive(packet);
                Printer.debugMessage(this.getClass(), String.format("received %s bytes", packet.getLength()));
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Truncate the data into a smaller byte array.
            int actualSize = packet.getLength();
            byte[] actualPacket = new byte[actualSize];
            System.arraycopy(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), data, 0, packet.getLength());

            // Deserialize the object.
            TestObject received = TestObject.deserialize(actualPacket); // Does not work.
            //TestObject received = TestObject.deserialize(packet.getData()); // Works fine?
            System.out.println("Server received object with value " + received.value);
        }
    }
}
```

**CLIENT (sending end)**

```
package net;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import utils.Printer;
import engine.board.GameBoard;

public class GameClient
{
    private static int BUFFER_SIZE = 64000;
    private static final int SERVER_LISTENING_PORT = 1234;
    private InetAddress serverIp;
    private DatagramSocket socket;
    private GameBoard game;
    private String clientName;

    public GameClient(String name, GameBoard game, String ipAddress)
    {
        this.game = game;
        this.clientName = name;
        try
        {
            this.socket = new DatagramSocket();
            this.serverIp = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
        } catch (SocketException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void sendData(byte[] data)
    {
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, serverIp, SERVER_LISTENING_PORT);

        try
        {
            socket.send(packet);
            Printer.debugMessage(this.getClass(), String.format("sent %d bytes to the server", data.length));;

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**TESTCODE**

```
import net.GameClient;
import net.GameServer;
import net.TestObject;


public class Scratchpad
{
    static GameServer server;
    static GameClient client;
    static GameClient client2;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Start the server
        server = new GameServer(null);
        server.start();

        // Init client (sender).
        client = new GameClient("client1", null, "localhost");

        // Create object to send.
        TestObject tester = new TestObject(1234);

        // Send the object.
        client.sendData(TestObject.serialize(tester));
        //client2.sendData("hello world".getBytes());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any of that. You can just deserialize from the original byte[] array. It will stop at the end of the object. Any trailing stuff at the end is just ignored.

However you can simplify your new code considerably, to this:

```
    TestObject received = TestObject.deserialize(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength());
```

and change your deserialize method(s) to this:

```
public static TestObject deserialize(byte[] data, int offset, int length)
{
    try
    {
        ObjectInputStream iStream = new ObjectInputStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(data, offset, length));
        // etc ...
}
```

I would further revise it to allow it to throw exceptions rather than silently swallow them. Returning `null` is a particularly poor strategy, as `null` is an in-band value that could have been the value you were trying to transmit.

Comment: Oh great :) Thank you for that! I'm well aware of the exceptions but I was on my way trying to get something to work by experimenting. I will make the code more robust now that I understand! :) Thank you!